# Read frequency to voltage with Arduino

Tags: pwm, frequency

How to read frequency into voltage with Arduino with an external source of frequency of 0-1Khz max?

Comment: Wait, first of all what are you trying to achieve? Second, "what chip ... with arduino". Do you want an external IC or you want to do it with arduino?

Comment: yes external IC , im sorry for my english

Comment: What's wrong with using the Arduino to just measure the frequency directly?

Comment: i'm new with this things, but i found this pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqMeasure.html a library work with arduino for my range 0,1 - 1 KHz i think this will be fine , thank's for reply

Comment: I found this [link](http://pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqMeasure.html). This is a library and will work with Arduino for my range 0,1 - 1 KHz. I think this will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I used the LM2917 for this purpose:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf

That IC is a frequency to voltage converter, so it perfectly suits your need. According to some quick calculations I made it can go to some tens of kHz, so if your signal is up to 1kHz it should be fine.

Now, this is the answer to your question. But... You can easily read the frequency directly with the arduino... If your purpose was to read the frequency, I suggest you to read something about [the X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: i found this https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqMeasure.html a library work with arduino for my range 0,1 - 1 KHz i think this will be fine , thank's for reply

Comment: @FrancescoValla ok, so you simply asked the wrong question. Now, please edit your question (but do not remove the original part) saying that your purpose was not to convert, but rather to read the frequency, so with that library you managed to solve your problem..